# Is there a place to leave backpacks at UN headquarters before its tour?

Tags: new-york-city, tours, luggage-storage, landmarks

I'm planning to visit United Nations Headquarters during my NY visit. In the security details page they state that they aren't allowing backpacks and bags larger than 14" (35cm) wide x 13" (33cm) high x 4" (10cm) deep. Also they don't allow food or water. My backpack is a size of a 15" laptop carrier and there is no way I can leave it anyplace. I wondered whether they have any places to leave our backpacks until the tour ends. I checked in their website under FAQ there's no QnA related to this.

Do they really have any place to leave backpacks? I do not have anything valuable in my bag other than my clothes water bottle and food.

If they don't allow, is there any other way that I can leave my bag until the tour ends? Since I'm planning to visit other places after this I have to carry my backpack.

Anyone who has visited United Nations Headquarters and faced similar situation?

Answer (score 7):

> ***Q: Is there a bag check or coatroom?***
>
> A: No, all coats and back packs must be carried while on tour.  Please note that large bags and backpacks are not permitted and that ***there are currently no left luggage facilities available***. For more information, see the Security page.

(emphasis mine)

http://visit.un.org/content/frequently-asked-questions

In response to the edit - there are plenty of commercial luggage storage options around New York City, so it depends on where you are staying (you may be able to leave it with your hotel concierge if you need to check out).

I won't list any commercial luggage storage options as I haven't used any in New York City, so I can't give you recommendations - but a quick search for "left luggage new york" gives several options within walking distance to the UN HQ.